# Object on heap gets deleted right after creation

Tags: c++, class, object, heap-memory

I'm writing a Vector class for my uni the task is to create a method that mutates the elements of this "vector" class into an object of the class itself and returns this object.
My problem is that as soon as I create the Object I should return it gets deleted from the heap.

I create a new Object from the class itself with `new DynArray{}` and push back the nonmutated elements into the Object. The problem is that before I even can use the Object (push the elements into the "Vector") it got deleted and is not present anymore. Therefore the program crashes. How can I avoid **that** from happening?

The mutation should take place in the method `transform`.

header file:

```
#ifndef DYNARRAY_H
#define DYNARRAY_H
#include <array>
#include <exception>
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

class DynArray
{
public:
    DynArray();
    DynArray(int c);
    DynArray(DynArray& copyArr);
    ~DynArray();
    int& at(const int i);
    int size();
    int capacity();
    void print();
    void push_back(const int value);
    void pop_back();
    void erase(const int index);
    void apply(std::function<void(int&)> f);
    DynArray transform(std::function<int(int)> f);
    void sort();
    void sort(std::function<bool(int,int)> comp);


private:
    int _capacity;
    int _size;
    int * arr = nullptr;
};

#endif // DYNARRAY_H
```

class file:

```
#include <dynarray.h>

DynArray::DynArray(){
    DynArray(4);
}

DynArray::DynArray(int c) : _capacity{c+=c}, _size{0} {
    arr = new int[_capacity];
}

DynArray::DynArray(DynArray& copyArr) : _capacity{copyArr.capacity()}, _size{copyArr.size()}{
    arr = new int[_capacity];
    for(int i = 0; i < copyArr.size(); i++)
        arr[i] = copyArr.at(i);
}

DynArray::~DynArray(){
    delete [] arr;
}
```

...

```
int& DynArray::at(const int i){
    if( i >= 0 && i <= size() && size() > 0)
        return arr[i];
    else
        throw std::invalid_argument("illegal Index");
}

int DynArray::size(){
    return _size;
}

int DynArray::capacity(){
    return _capacity;
}
```

...

```
void DynArray::push_back(const int value){
    if(size() >=capacity()){
        int * tmp = arr;

        _capacity+=_capacity;
        arr = new int[_capacity];
        for(int i = 0; i < size(); i++){
            arr[i] = tmp[i];
        }

        delete [] tmp;

        tmp = nullptr;

        arr[size()] = value;
        _size++;
    }else{
        arr[size()] = value;
        _size++;
    }
}

void DynArray::pop_back(){
    if(size() == 0)
        throw std::runtime_error("Cant delete a non existing element");
    else{
        at(size()-1) = 0;
        _size--;
    }
}

void DynArray::erase(const int index){
    if( index >= 0 && index < size() && size() > 0){
        for(int i = index; i < (size()-1); i++){
            arr[i] = arr[i+1];
        }
        _size--;
    }else{
        throw std::invalid_argument("illegal Index");}
}
```

...

```
DynArray DynArray::transform(std::function<int(int)> f){
    DynArray * copyArr = new DynArray();
    for(int i = 0; i < size()-1; i++)
        copyArr->push_back(at(i));

    for(int i = 0; i < copyArr->size()-1; i++)
        f(copyArr->at(i));

    return *copyArr;
}
```

main:

```
int main()
{
    DynArray a(1);
    a.push_back(1);
    a.push_back(3);
    a.push_back(44);
    a.push_back(677);
    a.push_back(23423);
    a.push_back(312);
    a.push_back(5645);
    a.push_back(5645);
    a.push_back(5213145);
    a.push_back(561234785);
    a.push_back(5675467);

    a.print();
    std::cout << std::endl;

    a.pop_back();
    a.pop_back();

    a.print();
    std::cout << std::endl;

    a.erase(5);
    a.erase(0);

    a.print();
    std::cout << std::endl;

    DynArray bb;
    bb = a.transform(addOne);

    bb.print();
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Changed the default and copy constructor as suggested:

```
DynArray::DynArray() : _capacity{4}, _size{0}{}
...
DynArray::DynArray(const DynArray& copyArr) : _capacity{copyArr._capacity}, _size{copyArr._size}{
    arr = new int[_capacity];
    //createNewArray(_capacity);
    for(int i = 0; i < _size; i++)
        arr[i] = copyArr.arr[i];
}
```

Comment: `DynArray(DynArray& copyArr)` -> `DynArray(const DynArray& copyArr)`.

Comment: Please add your test code (the one that "creates a new Object from the class it self" and "pushes back the non mutated elements into the Object.")

Comment: In `transform`, you have memleak: `DynArray * copyArr = new DynArray();` -> `DynArray copyArr;`.

Comment: Please provide [mcve].

Comment: `f(copyArr->at(i))` seems strange, you probably wanted `copyArr->push_back(f(at(i)))`.

Comment: There are a number of problems with your code: I spotted two right away: `DynArray()` creates a throwaway `DynArray` but does not actually set any fields; `DynArray::transform` heap-allocates a `DynArray` and then returns a copy, leaking `copyArr`.

Comment: `DynArray::DynArray(){
    DynArray(4);
}` doesn't do what you expect, it should be `DynArray::DynArray() : DynArray(4)
{}`.

Comment: @Jarod42 i wanted to try it in two steps but didnt work. Thing is i cant even get to this step beacause the Object gets deleted before i even can access the `push_back` method

Comment: As stated, there are several errors in your code, in particular your default constructor. Increase warning level, and run your code through a debugger to easily spot the errors.

Comment: @Jarod42 Changed default constructor to `DynArray::DynArray() : _capacity{4}, _size{0}{
}` changed copy constructor to `DynArray::DynArray(const DynArray& copyArr) : _capacity{copyArr._capacity}, _size{copyArr._size}{
    arr = new int[_capacity];
    for(int i = 0; i < _size; i++)
        arr[i] = copyArr.arr[i];
}`

Comment: `for(int i = 0; i < size()-1; i++)`: why `-1`?

Comment: Yeah that was weird idk. iI'm kind of feed up with this method because Im working several hours on it now.

Comment: okay i found one of my errors. Forgot to add `arr = new int[_capacity];` to my default constructor. The programm now works. Thanks for the help @Jarod42 though i still dont get why const was needed in the copy constructor. I dont quiet get why my memory gets leaked if @Botje could elaborate that, I'd be gratefull